# How to destroy Application listener object in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using libgdx, my code is like this,

```
public class MyActivity extends AndroidApplication {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //here i have initialized my application listener object
    initialize(new MyApplicationListener(),false);
    //other code
    }
}

//MyApplicationListener.java
public class MyApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener {

    public void create(){}
    public void render(){}
    public void dispose() {
        //diposing all resources
    }
}
```

Now my question is when iam finishing my `MyActivity.java`, the `dispose()`-method in `MyApplicationListener.java` was not getting called. Therefore my game was affecting from OOM exception.I have also tried to call the dispose method manually, but few objects were remaining as it is in the heap.

Answer (score 0):

To start from scratch,  open the **gdx-setup-ui.jar** from the downloaded libGDx zip folder. Export the created three project folders to Eclipse. Use it as reference to find out how to run it. See instructions for details on how to use this jar file.